# twython upload_profile_image image parameter is missing

Tags: twython

I am writing a short python script to play around with the twython API:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from twython import Twython
#encryption info
consumerKey = ''
consumerSecret = ''
accessToken = ''
accessTokenSecret = ''
#create instance of Twitter api
api = Twython(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api.update_status(status=sys.argv)  # post a new tweet
image = open('/home/pi/Downloads/kermit.jpg', 'rb')
api.update_profile_image(avatar=image)
```

but when I run the script like the following:

```
sudo python tweeter.py 'i love twitter'
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "tweeter.py", line 13, in 
>           api.update_profile_image(avatar=image)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/endpoints.py", line 474, in update_profile_image
>           return self.post('account/update_profile_image', params=params)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 268, in post
>           return self.request(endpoint, 'POST', params=params, version=version)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 258, in request
>           api_call=url)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython/api.py", line 194, in _request
>           retry_after=response.headers.get('X-Rate-Limit-Reset'))
>       twython.exceptions.TwythonError: Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), image parameter is missing.

Am I passing in the wrong parameter to this function? If so, how do I properly pass in the image as a parameter?